# como convertir consulta sql en una lista en c#

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy trabajando en n capas donde pretendo hacer una consulta a sql de una tabla que guarda diferentes pesos de un usuario a lo largo del tiempo, la idea es guardar los datos de ese user en una lista en la capa común de usuario(cache), la idea es que obteniendo el resultado de esta lista yo pueda mostrar los datos en una grafica solo de las fechas que yo coloque como limites en este caso @FromDate y @ToDate

**Consulta SQL**

```
USE [FitnessApp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GraficoPeso]    Script Date: 17/01/2021 18:53:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[GraficoPeso]
@UserID int,
@FromDate date,
@ToDate date
as
select 
Weight,
lastupdate

from UserWeight where UserWeight.UserID=@UserID
```

**Capa de datos**

```
public DataTable ObtenerGraficaPeso(int UserID, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "GraficoPeso";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserID;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = FromDate;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ToDate;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    var table = new DataTable();
                    table.Load(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                    return table;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Capa de dominio**

```
 public class ReportePeso
    {
        //Valores para la grafica de peso 
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public void PesoGrafica(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
        {
            //fechas
            StartDate = FromDate;
            EndDate = ToDate;
            //obtener datos de la consulta
            var orden = new UserData();
            var result = orden.ObtenerGraficaPeso(UserCache.UserID, FromDate, ToDate);

        }
    }
```

he visto procedimientos para convertir la consulta a lista pero no he logrado hacer funcionar ninguno, hasta aquí he llegado sin errores, como ven no he comenzado la parte de presentación pero es por que aun no tengo la lista para mostrarla en la grafica, pueden ayudarme dándome un ejemplo parecido al mío o un código de lista que pueda utilizar que sea fácil de entender?

Comment: Ese datatable se puede convertir en un IEnumerable (usando linq?)? y luego de eso, se puede convertir en un list?

Comment: puedes darme un ejemplo aplicable?

Comment: @Ganinox, hola,  podrias hacerme saber si la respuesta te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = (from r in dt.Rows select
    new
    {
       Weigth = Convert.ToInt32(d["Weigth"]),
       OtroCampo = ...
    }).ToList();
```

Hacemos una consulta en **Linq** la cual va a devolver una **lista de un objeto anónimo**, que tendrá tantos campos como desees, en este caso ejemplifico con el **campo Weigth**. Este campo del objeto guardará el valor equivalente que tiene **Weigth** en la tabla. Si quisiéramos guardar por ejemplo un campo digamos que sea **string**, sería por ejemplo:

```
OtroCampo = r["Nombre"].ToString();
```

Importante que tengas en cuenta la conversión de cada campo.

Entre los corchetes va el nombre del campo en la tabla.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: te falto el where

Comment: @RamiroBarone,  yo creo q no, el where esta en la consulta que el ejecuta y este conjunto de datos es el que se carga en el datatable, ya en el datatable los datos que se cargan son el resultado de la consulta que el previamente hizo, me parece que yo no tengo que hacer ningun where