# Mostrar datos de una consulta en una lista

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente método en una capa llamada DataAccess y en la clase Consultas, a ese metodo le mando un parámetro desde la capa Presentation donde están los formularios

**Esto esta en la capa Presentation**

```
string Num;             
Num = obtenerDatosCloudFleet.number.ToString();
Consultas c = new Consultas();
c.ListarEnvioFilas(Convert.ToString(Num));
```

**Esto esta en la capa DataAccess clase consultas**

```
public void  ListarEnvioFilas(string num)
    {
        Comando.Connection = Conexionsql.AbrirConexion();
        Comando.CommandText = "SP_EnvioFilas";
        Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", num);
        Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Comando.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

**Al mandarle ese parámetro se supone que ejecuta la siguiente consulta**

```
ALTER PROC SP_EnvioFilas
@Number NVARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT (CASE WHEN X.FilasEnCero IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.FilasEnCero END ) AS FilasEnCero,
X.workOrderNumber,Y.FilasTrabajos,Y.workOrderNumber FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(T1.workOrderNumber) AS FilasEnCero, T1.workOrderNumber
FROM [dbo].[tbl_EncabezadOrdenT] T0
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_DetalleOrdenT] T1 ON T1.workOrderNumber = T0.number
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_DetalleOrdenR] T2 ON T2.laborId = T1.idCloudFleet
WHERE T0.number = @Number AND T1.unitCost = 0  
GROUP BY T1.workOrderNumber) X
FULL JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(T1.workOrderNumber) AS FilasTrabajos,T1.workOrderNumber
FROM [dbo].[tbl_EncabezadOrdenT] T0
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_DetalleOrdenT] T1 ON T1.workOrderNumber = T0.number
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_DetalleOrdenR] T2 ON T2.laborId = T1.idCloudFleet
WHERE T0.number = @Number 
GROUP BY T1.workOrderNumber)Y ON X.workOrderNumber = Y.workOrderNumber
```

**Esta consulta me devuelve esto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es mostrar el resultado que me devuelve esto en una lista, para trabajar con estos datos en la capa presentación

Es decir que la lista me debería quedar acá pero ya con los datos que devuelve la consulta

```
   string Num;             
    Num = obtenerDatosCloudFleet.number.ToString();
    Consultas c = new Consultas();
    c.ListarEnvioFilas(Convert.ToString(Num));
    List<>....
```

Comment: Y el problema es...?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421472/como-convertir-consulta-sql-en-una-lista-en-c/421478#421478 entra aqui y dime si te sirvio